# How to get default type which function returns by custom TypeMap

Tags: typescript

I have function which returns promise with type which provided by generic

```
const api = <Model>(url: string) => Promise<Model>
```

For now I always need to set Type of returned data

```
const data = await api<{id: string, name: string}>('google.com')
```

How can I check if `url` includes in `CustomMap` then returns type from my map.

For example:

```
interface CustomMap {
  'google.com': {id: string, name: string}
  'amazon.com': {count?: number}
}
```

So I wanna get `{id: string, name: string}` when I call `api('google.com')`

If url not defined in map I want to get Type from input Generic

```
const data = await api('youtube.com') // error: Must provided some type
const data = await api<YoutubeResponse>('youtube.com') // ok
```

Comment: Given they return different types - why have one function at all? `await google();` `await youtube();` <- wouldn't this be better?

Comment: No because in real world I have 100+ known routes and `Infinity` unkonown

Answer (score 0):

There are other ways to structure this that might be better, but what you are asking for is pretty straight-forward.  I am separating the arguments for the `domain` and the `path` so that you can get autocomplete support on the domain name.  I am saying that the domain **must** be one of the keys in your custom map, so you'll get an error if you try to access something with an unknown return type.

This `typedApi` function takes the domain and the path and then calls the root `api` function with the correct return type based on the domain.

```
const typedApi = <Domain extends keyof CustomMap>(domain: Domain, path: string): Promise<CustomMap[Domain]> => {
  return api<CustomMap[Domain]>(`https://${domain}${path}`);
}
```

```
// Promise<{ id: string; name: string; }>
const gData = typedApi('google.com', '/some-path');

// Promise<{ count?: number }>
const aData = typedApi('amazon.com', '/some-path');
```

[Playground Link](https://tsplay.dev/Qmbq2N)

Comment: This is not what I want.
Sometimes I need to call unknown domains, so for this case I need to define custom type of returned value